# Derivatives with Jacobian Matrix Composition

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

Let $h: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x,y,z)=g(x^2-y^2,y^2-z^2)$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function such that $\nabla g(0,0)=(1,2)$. Determine the directional derivative of $h$ in the point $(1,1,1)$ along $\vec{v}=(2,0,1)$.

Though it might be possible to solve this problem without the Jacobian Matrix, I would really like to know how to aproach this problem with it. I'm having difficulty, since the dimensions of the matrix don't correspond to what's expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "trick" here is that you are really working with the composition $g\circ f$, where $g$ is as defined in the problem and $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $f(x,y,z)=(x^2-y^2,y^2-z^2)$. Working with these you should get a 1x2 matrix (the Jacobian of $g$, evaluated at $f(1,1,1)=(0,0)$) times a 2x3 matrix (the Jacobian of $f$, evaluated at $(1,1,1)$):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2x & -2y & 0 \\ 0 & 2y & -2z
\end{bmatrix}_{(1,1,1)} = \begin{bmatrix}2x & 2y & -4z\end{bmatrix}_{(1,1,1)}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & -4\end{bmatrix}
$$

And the dimensions of this product are as expected since the composition $g\circ f$ maps from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$. You can then treat the resulting 1x3 matrix as a gradient to compute the directional derivative:

$$
\mathbf{D}_{\overrightarrow{v}}(g\circ f)(1,1,1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & -4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}=0 
$$